# animate every char of an html element text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i want to animate a string of text taken from an html element using jquery:

```
<h1>Animate</h1>
```

for the jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "h1" ).animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
     .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );

});
```

this animates the whole h1 text value, however i want to animate each character in the h1 text.

the second jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var animateChar = $("h1").text();
    for(i=0; i<animateChar.length; i++) {

        //alert(i + ': ' + animateChar.charAt(i));
        // for every animateChar.charAt[i] want to run this
        //jquery animation.
        //$( "h1" ).animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
        //.animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );

        }
 });
```

this is the bit where im stuck. thanks

Comment: you'll have to wrap each character in a span - text nodes are indivisible.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible without separating out every character in to another container such as a `<span>`. I guess you could do that first, then loop through them.

Comment: yeh thats interesting idea!! let me try it out!! thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery functions on DOM elements. Not on characters apart. You should use different DOM elements for each character:

```
<span>A</span><span>N</span><span>I</span>...
```

with something like this must do the trick

```
$('span').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        that.animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
            .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
    },that.index()*100);
});​
```

-edit-

working [**jSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aA8Un/)

-edit 2-

without messy HTML [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aA8Un/1/)(well it's still messy, but javascript makes it messy ;) )

Comment: I agree. But don't flood your html code with such unsemantical stuff. Use [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) tool.

Comment: @Marakoss True. Made an edit (still making my HTML messy on clientside) with readable template html

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="animate">A</span><span class="animate">n</span><span class="animate">i</span><span class="animate">m</span><span class="animate">a</span><span class="animate">t</span><span class="animate">e</span>

$(document).ready(function() {

   var count = 0;       

   function animation(elm) {
       if(count == $(".animate").length)
       {
          clearInterval(id);
          return;
       }

       $( elm ).animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
     .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
     count++;
   }

   var id = setInterval(animation($(".animate")[count]), 3200);//Give time for animation to run.

});
```

This will animate each character.

Comment: this deosnt animate letters, it animates all of them at once! :))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your HTML clean, I'd add the following method to wrap your characters in `span` tags. Execute this onLoad using `wrapCharacters($("h1"))` before you animate anything, then animate characters returned by `$(".animate")`.

```
function wrapCharacters(obj)
{
    var html = '';
    var text = obj.text();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        html += '<span class="animate">' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
    obj.html(html);
}
```

Comment: can you clarify using this more!!

Comment: At the start of the function run onLoad execute this on any of the elements you want to animate like this (`wrapCharacters($("h1"))` is fine if you only have one h1 tag, otherwise loop them and do `wrapCharacters` on each one - you can use `$.each` for this), it should wrap all characters in a container with a span of the appropriate class, then use rsplak's answer on how to animate those spans.